# Xcode 6 open Assistant Editor in New Window

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I feel like I have read every link on `Google` pertaining to this question, but none that I have read have helped.

All I want to do is view my `Storyboard` layout on the left monitor, and on my right monitor, in a new window, have the `Assistant Editor` open to "Preview" for my `Storyboard` so that I can preview the different devices sizes (clicking different storyboard views on the left screen should update the assistant editor preview on the right). This seems so simple, but has not proved to be.

**Please tell me this is possible.**

EDIT: [This guy seems to have it working](http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/09/27/maximizing-the-preview-assistant-editor-in-xcode-6/) but following the steps didn't work for me.

Comment: It isn't possible but it would make a great feature request! I hope you'll file a bug with Apple.

Comment: @matt - Crazy, this seems like such a no brainer thing to have...

Comment: Great question, surprised you haven't had more up votes already.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible.. and it's awesome:

I do have this working after following the instructions linked in the OP. I think the author left out that you need to click on the view controller that you're editing in BOTH instances of the story board window to see the changes update. Then as you're editing on your main window the changes will update to the open storyboard and thus the preview will update as well. I was able to test this and achieved a somewhat desired result.

In case the link goes dead here are the instructions lined out

Here’s how you can set this up…

1. In the Project Navigator pane, single-click a storyboard/XIB file to open it in the main Xcode window.
2. Now double-click that same file to open it in a new window.
3. Move the new window to another monitor and maximize it
   (So now you have the story board on 2 windows)
4. Click on the new window to make sure it has input focus, then type Option+Command+Enter to open an assistant editor in that window.
5. In the assistant editor’s jump bar click on ‘Automatic‘ to open the drop-down menu (see the screenshot below if you don’t know what this means).
6. Click on the ‘Preview‘ menu item to open the preview editor.
7. Click and hold next to the assistant editor’s jump bar, then drag up or left (depending on which editor layout you prefer; vertical or horizontal), to maximize the preview’s screen real estate.

Lastly... the part the author left out is that you need to select the view controller you want to edit in BOTH story board windows and then just drag the preview window to cover more of the screen.

It's not pretty but it's effective.

Edit: wording and grammar :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible (Xcode 6.3.1 at the time of writing). <s>The best you can do is open your storyboard in one window, open it again in a new window, open the preview, and slide the assistant editor as far left as possible. The preview won't take up the entire window, but it'll be pretty close.</s>

Comment: But if you do that, choosing objects in the storyboard on the left monitor won't update the preview window on the right. They are essentially disconnected.