# Xcode: How to show Preview in separate window instead of showing in Assistant editor?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

When I'm making edits in storyboard I know how to show the preview in the assistant editor (as shown in the below screen shot).

How to show the preview in a separate window, so that I'll be able to drag it to my the screen attached to my computer?

[image]

**UPDATE:** Adding few more images to clarify what is the "Storyboard Preview":

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198556/xcode-6-open-assistant-editor-in-new-window

Comment: @AjithRNayak yes, it really looks like a duplicate. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

In XCode 7 I managed to do this by selecting File -> New window, then adding a preview-part teh same way you illustrate above. I then drag it to my secondary screen resize everything to give a good preview of the screen sizes I want.